# Not able to select option in dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am adding adding options to the dropdown using jquery as below.

```
function GetAssociates(StoreNum,dropdownid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Appointment.aspx/BindAssociates",
            data: "{storeNumber:" + StoreNum + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                var rs = result.d;
                var select = $("#" + dropdownid);
                //var select = document.getElementById(dropdownid);

                for (var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
                    var opt = rs[i].trim();
                    select.append(new Option(opt,opt));
                }
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert("Failed to load dropdown" + result);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly and I can see the values in the dropwdown. Now I am trying to select particular value using jquery as below but it is not selecting the value.

```
$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val("MyValue");
```

If I add value at design time as below the above code of selecting MyValue works fine.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAptAssociateName" runat="server" CssClass="DropdownList">
            <asp:ListItem>SomeValue</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>MyValue</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Please help me doing this.

Comment: make sure your value "MyValue" is available when you run the code `$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val("MyValue");`. If the option is added after you want to set the value, your value can't be set and the value won't change

Comment: I am building dropdown before selecting it and I can see those in the dropdown on the page

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/h31nc2n6/ I am setting the value when the option is already available. Check your ID of the select or the value-attribute in the option you want to set. not the text, but the value is important

Comment: @Mephiztopheles - dude!! I mentioned it works if the values are added at design time.

Comment: Ajax calls are asynchronous. so when your requests are going out and you call then the function to select, the response is not already back. Therefore you have the success property in ajax calls. if you're doing: `GetAssociates();$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val("MyValue");` it will clearly not work. Rebuild your code to add a callback when ajax call successed or return the ajax call in your GetAssociates

Comment: @Mephiztopheles Make sense. Thats what I am doing. But in the success method (see code above) of GetAssociates I am building dropdown. Could you please help me rewriting the code.

Comment: Of course i can :) I'll post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go
i can't resist to add jsDoc :D

```
/**
 *
 * @param StoreNum
 * @param dropdownid
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @constructor
 */
function GetAssociates( StoreNum, dropdownid, callback ) {
    $.ajax( {
        type       : "POST",
        url        : "Appointment.aspx/BindAssociates",
        data       : "{storeNumber:" + StoreNum + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType   : "json",
        success    : function ( result ) {
            var rs     = result.d;
            var select = $( "#" + dropdownid );
            //var select = document.getElementById(dropdownid);

            for ( var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++ ) {
                var opt = rs[ i ].trim();
                select.append( new Option( opt, opt ) );
            }
            // apply will run the function with 'this' as first committed argument-> select
            callback.apply( select );
        },
        error      : function ( result ) {
            alert( "Failed to load dropdown" + result );
        }
    } );
}

function load() {
    // GetAssociates is a constructor due to uppercased name
    // my idea will mark this as error -> never mind in your case
    GetAssociates( 1, "MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName", function () {
        this.val( "MyValue" );
    } );
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this and i will revert.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.val()` wrong. You get the value by doing the following:

```
var myVal =  $("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val();
```

You set the value to `MyValue` by doing the following:

```
$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val("MyValue");
```

Comment: I think he's trying to set instead read. then he's using the function the right way. In case he edited his answer, ignore this comment

Comment: As I mentioned the same code works when I add the option at design time

Comment: @Prabi well what that means is that your `jQuery` is being executed before that element has been loaded into the page, so it doesn't see any value for it. You may need to mess around with the point in which your `js` file is loaded into the page

Comment: @Adjit - I am calling the GetAssociates function before selecting drowpdown value. However I am doing both things in the same function. Does this causing it?

Comment: @Prabi Well, before you select the value obviously it will be empty or the default value of the dropdown. If you then get the value again when the function is called and it is still empty that means your jquery code was initialized before your input has been loaded into the dom

Comment: @Adjit - This is what I am doing in the same function. 'function EnableEditMode() {GetAssociates('1234',"MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName")};  $("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val("MyValue");'